# Как сохранить данные при обновлении приложения C#

Tags: c#, sql

Есть приложение, которое работает с локальной базой данных, которая создается при установке приложения. Проблема в том, что при обновлении программы, база данных тоже обновляется и заменяется на пустую. Как этого избежать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо пересоздания базы надо использовать скрипты для её обновления на новую схему, когда такое требуется.

Comment: Это называется "миграция".

Comment: @aepot, пожалуй да. Хотя, слово "миграция" чаще встречается при автоматической генерации скриптов обновления (entity framework и другие), а при ручном написании скриптов обновления что-то не очень помню, чтобы их так называли...

Comment: Именно так и называют. Базе все равно, кто или что писало скрипты :) Процесс одинаковый.